# chartjs-plugin-annotation won't draw anything

Tags: chart.js

I have a chartjs line chart setup and I'm trying to draw a horizontal annotation line across the chart at a fixed value.  But **nothing happens** and no errors in console.

I've included the chartjs-plugin-annotation.js such as this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/0.5.7/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
```

Then added this into the `options:` (which should add a 2px thick line across the chart as value "25"):

```
            annotation: {
                drawTime: 'afterDraw',
                annotations: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    id: 'line',
                    mode: 'horizontal',
                    scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                    value: 25,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: 'black'
                }]
            },
```

Full code for the chart is here:

```
    var temperaturechart = new Chart($('#temperaturechart'), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Temperature',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 132, 3, 0.1)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(252, 132, 3, 1)',
                data: [{"x":"2020-05-21 14:00:00","y":27.28},{"x":"2020-05-21 16:00:00","y":28.64},{"x":"2020-05-21 18:00:00","y":29.83},{"x":"2020-05-21 20:00:00","y":20.24},{"x":"2020-05-21 22:00:00","y":21.63},{"x":"2020-05-22 00:00:00","y":30.34},{"x":"2020-05-22 02:00:00","y":19.01},{"x":"2020-05-22 04:00:00","y":18.88}],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            annotation: {
                drawTime: 'afterDraw',
                annotations: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    id: 'line',
                    mode: 'horizontal',
                    scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                    value: 25,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: 'black'
                }]
            },
            aspectRatio: 2.5,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day',
                        unitStepSize: 1,
                        displayFormats: {
                            'day': 'MMM DD'
                        }
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: false,
                        labelString: 'Date'
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        tickMarkLength: 8,
                        zeroLineColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        maxRotation: 90,
                        minRotation: 45,
                        padding: 10
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Temperature'
                    }
                }]
            },

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had made a dumb mistake of including both Chart.min.js and then later on Chart.bundle.min.js also.

So something like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/0.5.7/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>

...other code...


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Deleting this later Chart.bundle.min.js solved the problem.